# encoding is ignored in fs.readFile

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read the contents of a properties file in node. this is my call:

```
fs.readFile("server/config.properties", {encoding: 'utf8'}, function(err, data ) {
   console.log( data );
});
```

The console prints a buffer:

```
<Buffer 74 69 74 69 20 3d 20 74 6f 74 6f 0a 74 61 74 61 20 3d 20 74 75 74 75>
```

when I replace the code with this:

```
fs.readFile("server/config.properties", function(err, data ) {
   console.log( data.toString('utf8') );
});
```

it works fine. But the [node documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) says the String is converted to utf8 if the encoding is passed in the options

the output of node --version is v0.10.2

What am I missing here?

thank you for your support

Comment: Both ways work for me. You may be using an older version of node? I'm using v0.10.1

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Depending on the version of Node you're running, the argument may be just the `encoding`:

```
fs.readFile("server/config.properties", 'utf8', function(err, data ) {
   console.log( data );
});
```

The 2nd argument changed to `options` [with v0.10](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Api-changes-between-v0.8-and-v0.10):

> - FS `readFile()`, `writeFile()`, `appendFile()` and their Sync counterparts now take an `options` object (but the old API, an `encoding` string, is still supported)

For former documentation:

- [v0.8.22](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.22/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback)
- [v0.6.21](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.21/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback)

Answer (score 9):

You should change `{encoding: 'utf8'}` to {encoding: 'utf-8'}, for example:

```
fs.readFile("server/config.properties", {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err, data ) {
console.log( data );
});
```

Comment: anyway fs not support some charsets like `ISO-8859-1` for this reason I've needle to use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14551669/2979435