# How to read non-english character like: "Ä,ö" from file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

When I read a JSON file in node.js the non-english character display as '?' instead of the origin character.
The results from the stream is already in the wrong charset.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname,'../data.json'), 'utf8');

        stream.on('error', function (error) {
            response.status(500).send({ msg: error.message });
        })

        stream.pipe(response);
    }
}
```

**File example:**

```
   {  
       data: [  
          {"id":"111","name":"Dr. Per Änglund","phone":"7350-01794"},  
          {"id":"22","name":"Lars Änglund","phone":"1942-463945"}  
      ]  
   }
```

Comment: How are you reading the JSON, post code.

Comment: I post the code in the question

Comment: Please provide an example of this file (gist).

Comment: I add an example in the question

Comment: @Sari if you're seeing the characters wrong in the browser check my answer, otherwise specify if the result from the stream is already in the wrong charset.

Comment: The results from the stream is already in the wrong charset

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into consideration the [encoding](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) of the file you're trying to read.

Assuming you read your file using

```
fs.readFile("test.txt", function(err, data) {
   console.log( data );
});
```

You can simply add the `'utf8'` argument to specify that you're trying to read an [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) file:

```
fs.readFile("test.txt", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
   console.log( data );
});
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772925/encoding-is-ignored-in-fs-readfile).