# What encodings are available Node.js

Tags: node.js, encoding

I'm trying to figure out what encodings are available in node.js.

The documentation (http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding) says:

`Allocates a new buffer containing the given str. encoding defaults to 'utf8'.`

but nowhere is specified a list of available encodings. Maybe I missed it.

I'm working on script which should be able to output in wide range of encodings. So far I know only about utf8 as doc is saying :)

Thx, Jaro.

Comment: Check out [`iconv-lite`](https://npmjs.org/package/iconv-lite) if you need more encodings than supported natively by Node.

Comment: Have to admit, I came here in exactly the same circumstance. The nodejs documentation is still poorly structured and not including any links/references to supported encodings for read and write operations is bad.

Answer (score 7):

Encodings available in Node.js:

> - `ascii`: For 7-bit ASCII data only. This encoding is fast and will strip the high bit if set.
> - `utf8`: Multibyte encoded Unicode characters. Many web pages and other document formats use UTF-8.
> - `utf16le`: 2 or 4 bytes, little-endian encoded Unicode characters. Surrogate pairs (U+10000 to U+10FFFF) are supported.
> - `ucs2`: Alias of `utf16le`.
> - `base64`: Base64 encoding. When creating a Buffer from a string, this encoding will also correctly accept "URL and Filename Safe
>     Alphabet" as specified in RFC 4648, Section 5.
> - `latin1`: A way of encoding the Buffer into a one-byte encoded string (as defined by the IANA in RFC 1345, page 63, to be the Latin-1
>     supplement block and C0/C1 control codes).
> - `binary`: Alias for 'latin1'.
> - `hex`: Encode each byte as two hexadecimal characters.

Source: [Node 12 Buffer documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings)

Comment: by default buffer does not support iso-8859-1. I googled around and found another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551608/cant-find-encodings-for-node-js . The solution is based on node-iconv npm. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in order to clarify lastest nodejs encoding explaination. I paste from nodejs document. v4+ does't deprated binary

> The character encodings currently supported by Node.js include:
>
> 'ascii' - For 7-bit ASCII data only. This encoding is fast and will strip the high bit if set.
>
> 'utf8' - Multibyte encoded Unicode characters. Many web pages and other document formats use UTF-8.
>
> 'utf16le' - 2 or 4 bytes, little-endian encoded Unicode characters. Surrogate pairs (U+10000 to U+10FFFF) are supported.
>
> 'ucs2' - Alias of 'utf16le'.
>
> 'base64' - Base64 encoding. When creating a Buffer from a string, this encoding will also correctly accept "URL and Filename Safe Alphabet" as specified in RFC 4648, Section 5.
>
> 'latin1' - A way of encoding the Buffer into a one-byte encoded string (as defined by the IANA in RFC 1345, page 63, to be the Latin-1 supplement block and C0/C1 control codes).
>
> 'binary' - Alias for 'latin1'.
>
> 'hex' - Encode each byte as two hexadecimal characters.