# node.js how to repreduce PHP MD5 encryption

Tags: php, node.js, md5, salt, password-encryption

I'm converting an existing php based website to a node.js app, and I need to reproduce this encryption method from php to js.

```
private static $_passwordSalt = 'd2g6IOP(U(&Â§)%UÂ§VUIPU(HN%V/Â§Â§URerjh0Ã¼rfqw4zoÃ¶qe54gÃŸ0Ã¤Q"LOU$3wer';
public static function getCryptedPassword($password = 'password') {
    return sha1(md5(self::$_passwordSalt.$password));
}
```

So far I've tried this but it does not return the same results:

```
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
        var salt = 'd2g6IOP(U(&Â§)%UÂ§VUIPU(HN%V/Â§Â§URerjh0Ã¼rfqw4zoÃ¶qe54gÃŸ0Ã¤Q"LOU$3wer'
        var md5Hash = md5(password + salt);
        var hash = sha1(md5Hash);
        return hash;
};
```

Comment: For a start, you're doing `md5(salt, password)` in your PHP and `md5(password, salt)` in your JavaScript.

Comment: ive tried all the different combinations: md5(salt,password),md5(password,salt),sh1(md5,salt),sha1(salt,md5), but still it doesnt work

Comment: You shouldn't be using md5 or sha1 or any combination of the two to store passwords. In PHP the best way to store passwords is [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash) which (currently) uses bcryt. Here's a node.js implementation of bcrypt: https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs

Comment: You know this is an awful unsecure way to work with passwords? A static salt is actually not a salt, and MD5 is ways too fast to hash passwords, you can brute-force about [8 Giga MD5/s](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance). You should use a slow hash function with a cost factor instead, see the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try these:

```
    var crypto = require('crypto');
var salt = 'd2g6IOP(U(&Â§)%UÂ§VUIPU(HN%V/Â§Â§URerjh0Ã¼rfqw4zoÃ¶qe54gÃŸ0Ã¤Q"LOU$3wer'
var password = 'pass';

var hashMd5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(salt + password).digest("hex");
var hasSha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(hasMd5).digest("hex");
console.log(hashSha1);
```

as file: hash.js

And as hash.php these code:

```
<?php

$_passwordSalt = 'd2g6IOP(U(&Â§)%UÂ§VUIPU(HN%V/Â§Â§URerjh0Ã¼rfqw4zoÃ¶qe54gÃŸ0Ã¤Q"LOU$3wer';
$password = 'pass';

//echo md5("phinware");
echo sha1(md5($_passwordSalt.$password));
echo "\n";
```

And than execute both files:

- > php hash.php
- > node hash.js

My results:

both: 3cbd1242e8e510a16f39d7e0bfd18a0e03d0de3f

Answer (score 1):

php:

```
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';
echo md5($a.$b);
```

equals to node.js:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var a = 'b', b = 'b';
var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
md5.update(xml, 'utf8');
md5.update(config.secret, 'utf8');
console.log(md5.digest('hex'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using crypto module:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
    var salt = 'd2g6IOP(U(&Â§)%UÂ§VUIPU(HN%V/Â§Â§URerjh0Ã¼rfqw4zoÃ¶qe54gÃŸ0Ã¤Q"LOU$3wer';
    var hashStr = password + salt;
    var md5Hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(hashStr).digest('hex');
    var sha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(md5Hash).digest('hex');
    console.log(sha1); 
    return sha1;
};
```

Comment: nope, this return a string which has less charecters so i think its wrong. ive tried to wrap this with the sha1 encryption but its still wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that a hash algorithm works on byte values, and you are using string values. This means that encoding will come in to play here, and from what I know PHP uses latin1 by default, while node.js uses utf-8.

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update(hashStr, 'ascii').digest('hex')
```

I'm not sure if ascii only handles 7-bit ascii or actual extended charsets like latin1, but it seems to be the only one supported directly in the `update()` method. If you need to control the extended charset, you should create a Buffer from the correct encoding, and use that as parameter to `update()` instead. The built in support in node.js is rather limited:

```
Buffer.isEncoding = function(encoding) {
  switch ((encoding + '').toLowerCase()) {
    case 'hex':
    case 'utf8':
    case 'utf-8':
    case 'ascii':
    case 'binary':
    case 'base64':
    case 'ucs2':
    case 'ucs-2':
    case 'utf16le':
    case 'utf-16le':
    case 'raw':
      return true;

    default:
      return false;
  }
};
```

And you should consider using some other tool to convert it. This thread ([List of encodings that Node.js supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551608/cant-find-encodings-for-node-js)) suggests using iconv or iconv-lite.

Of course, the same applies to SHA1, but since you are using SHA1 on a hex representation of an MD5, it would never fall out of 7-bit ascii (where latin1 and utf-8 would produce the same byte sequence).

Answer (score 0):

here is the currect solution

```
var md5 = require('MD5'),
    sha1 = require('sha1');

var salt = 'd2g6IOP(U(&Â§)%UÂ§VUIPU(HN%V/Â§Â§URerjh0Ã¼rfqw4zoÃ¶qe54gÃŸ0Ã¤Q"LOU$3wer';
var hash = sha1(md5(salt+password));
return hash;
```