# PHP md5 and JS hex_md5 does not match result on special characters

Tags: javascript, php

I have tried hashing a string in PHP7 using MD5 and the same in Javascript, but the results are different.. can someone explain me how to get this matched?

```php
//PHP Code
md5('1: ÏtÚë£');
```

```
//Javascript Code
hex_md5('1: ÏtÚë£');
```

I expect the result to match, but the actual output are the ff:

PHP: "3fbee32d8a25287ad7ccbf133d82bb54"

Javascript: "9a7246843cd0c5906f2e588f0997116b"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This link might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390385/node-js-how-to-repreduce-php-md5-encryption)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, what `hex_md5()` is (I can suggest it). Anyway, it's character encoding issue:

php/UTF-8:

```
3fbee32d8a25287ad7ccbf133d82bb54
```

php/LATIN-1:

```
9a7246843cd0c5906f2e588f0997116b
```

Comment: Yes, it's an encoding issue: https://gist.github.com/alexmuller/1178226 uses UTF char codes only

Comment: I think the library is broken. It converts strings to UTF-8, even if they are already UTF-8. In my opinion, a md5() (or general any checksum function) must accept the input data as given. The question of above is a good example, why I call it *broken*.