# Download an image using node-request, and fs Promisified, with no pipe in Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, fs, node-request

I have been struggling to succeed in downloading an image without piping it to fs. Here's what I have accomplished:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs')),
    requestAsync = Promise.promisify(require('request'));

function downloadImage(uri, filename){
    return requestAsync(uri)
        .spread(function (response, body) {
            if (response.statusCode != 200) return Promise.resolve();
            return fs.writeFileAsync(filename, body);
        })
       .then(function () { ... })

       // ...
}
```

A valid input might be:

```
downloadImage('http://goo.gl/5FiLfb', 'c:\\thanks.jpg');
```

I do believe the problem is with the handling of `body`.
I have tried casting it to a `Buffer` (`new Buffer(body, 'binary')` etc.) in several encodings, but all failed.

Thanks from ahead for any help!

Comment: Any idea how would one do that with streams?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to tell `request` that the data is binary:

```
requestAsync(uri, { encoding : null })
```

Documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#request-options-callback):

> `encoding` - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (**including the default value of undefined**) will be passed as the encoding parameter to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default).

So without that option, the body data is interpreted as UTF-8 encoded, which it isn't (and yields an invalid JPEG file).

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that. :)

Comment: This answer helped me finally save valid PDFs I was fetching with [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise). I tried [every encoding supported by Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14551669/3212415), but the resulting file was always corrupt (and larger than it should have been). Turns out the problem was how it was coming back to begin with. Adding `encoding: null` fixed it, and then it saved fine no matter which encoding I used during `fs.writeFile()`. Thanks!