# Unknown encoding CP500

Tags: node.js

I need to convert a String to a byte array by using the [CP500](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/CP500) encoding.

I tried this line:

`const byteArray = Buffer.from(someString, "cp500");`

Which led to:

`TypeError: Unknown encoding: cp500TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_ENCODING]: Unknown encoding: cp500`

I googled "node cp500" and looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551608/list-of-encodings-that-node-js-supports) but I wasn't able to find any information pointing to cp500 support in node/javascript.

In addition, I can't find any mention of a plugin that supports this specific encoding.

**Is there way to get a buffer of bytes from a string in node.js with the cp500 encoding?**

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codepage) package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [codepage package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/codepage) that was pointed by Xaqron in a comment.

I had to import it as:

`const codepage: typeof import('codepage').default = require('codepage');`

Then, I used the package's encode function as follows in order to encode my string:

`codepage.utils.encode(500, somestring, 'arr');`

Which corresponds to the target encoding.