# Reading binary data (pixel color) from a .bmp file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read a pixel color (RGB) from a `2x2` bmp file (72 bytes) where the 1st pixel color is `#ffc90e`:

[image]

The pixel color (BGR) starts at the position `62`.

[image]

So I'm trying to get that pixel color from nodeJS with the code below but I'm getting the wrong hex values. I've already tried changing the `readFileSync` params to `binary` and `utf-8`. With utf-8 it gets closer but not accurate.

```
'use strict'

const FS = require('fs') // https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
process.chdir(__dirname)

var stream = new Buffer.from(FS.readFileSync('2x2.bmp', 'utf-8'))
console.log(stream)
console.log(stream.toJSON())

var blue = stream.toString('hex', 62, 63)
var green = stream.toString('hex', 64, 65)
var red = stream.toString('hex', 66, 67)

console.log(red, green, blue)
```

The output is:

[image]

Which may vary if I change `readFileSync` param to `binary` or `utf-8`. But never accurate values are shown, although I can see them with an hex editor @ position `62` (picture above).

References:

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

[List of encodings that Node.js supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551608/list-of-encodings-that-node-js-supports)

**UPDATE**

I have tried different hex editors and all of them can read the correct binary data. Only node.js can't. Even [this](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/hexdump-for-windows.html) trivial hex editor can read it right but node.js can't:

[image]

I bet all my coins it is a node.js issue. (v12.16.2)

Comment: hmm, interesting question. I have done something similar before I think.

I believe images can be parsed as a bytearray, which is probably what you want. I'll look it up a bit more and get back when I have more details.

This is probably a good place to start https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#typed_array_views

Comment: @ZimriLeijen the reason I chose .bmp over other format is because it is possible to read a pixel color in a bitmap file directly. In jpeg I'd have to use a library or something.

Comment: @Azevedo You still need a library, or at least beyond the most basic trivial of efforts as bitmap (in the .bmp file format) can be of all sorts.  Some use indexed color.  And, `utf-8` is definitely *not* what you want... this is a binary format.  What is your screenshot of?

Comment: @Brad "can be of all sorts" -- not in this case. The scenario is as-is. Not all sorts of `.bmp`, just the one kind you can see in the hex editor picture.

Comment: Well I have tried and tried. The conclusion I get after so many `console.log()` is that nodejs' `readFileSync()` have some issues reading files with binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('color.bmp', (err, data) => {
    console.log([...data])
})
```

Output:

```
[
  66, 77,  70,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  54,   0,
   0,  0,  40,   0,   0,   0,   2,   0,   0,   0,   2,   0,
   0,  0,   1,   0,  24,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  16,   0,
   0,  0, 195,  14,   0,   0, 195,  14,   0,   0,   0,   0,
   0,  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
   0,  0,  14, 201, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0
]
```

Note the 14, 201, 255 near the end. That corresponds with ff, c9, 0e

for a 2x2 pixel image with the top left pixel the same yellow as you specified, and the rest white.

You can also use this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/bmp-js

Comment: It does works! For some reason `Buffer` messed it up, or I did.