# Hex to Hex String

Tags: javascript

I am converting hex to hex strings then came across 2 ways to do it using the `toString()` method:

- `toString('hex')`
- `toString(16)`

I see a lot of resources online also use toString('hex') but when I tried to use it, it gives out an error message: `RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36`.
The `toString(16)` works perfect.

But just for curiousity, what is the story behind this? Is the `toString('hex')` deprecated of some sort? Or is there any specific use-case when that is used instead of `toString(16)`

Example:

```
let num = 0x7

console.log('Convert using toSting(hex): ' + num.toString('hex')) // throws an error
console.log('Convert using toSting(16): ' + num.toString(16))
```

Comment: I've never seen `toString('hex')`, it's invalid. I don't think it's ever been valid. Whatever resource you used is probably just really low quality or AI generated or something

Comment: *Where* did you come across a sample using “hex”‽

Comment: As others already pointed out only valid argument is An integer in the range 2 through 36 specifying the base to use for representing the number value. Defaults to 10. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Comment: The `something.toString('hex')` applies when `something` is a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) in node.js

Comment: buffer.prototype.toString
usage: `buffer.toString(encoding, start, end);`
encoding - Optional. The encoding to use in the return value. Default 'utf8'

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli This is a valid answer. And it definitely clarifies my confusion. If we can re-open this post, please post this as an answer and I will accept. Thank you!!

Comment: I believe reopening this question and posting a valid answer will be beneficial to the community. The question is a valid question and there is a valid answer also (see @GabrielePetrioli's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toString(16)` is how you convert [Numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to a hex string, `.toString('hex')` is how you convert NodeJS's [Buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer) to a hex string.

For Numbers, `radix` is an optional parameter, which should be an integer from 2 to 36, with a default value of 10.

```js
toString([radix])
```

For Buffers, `encoding` is an optional parameter (with start and end also optional), which can be many [values](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/48f99e5f6a1b131eba35d43c75e96377c5b5cc8e/lib/buffer.js#L634:L724) (also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551669/12101554)) such as "ascii", "utf8", and, in this case, "hex", with the default value of "utf8".

```js
toString([encoding[, start[, end]]])
```

If you mix-match these, Number will throw a `RangeError` (`toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36`) and Buffer will throw a `TypeError` (`Unknown encoding: 16`)

Comment: Thanks for reopening this question and posting a valid answer! I'm sure this would help a lot of people in the future!